# Does there exist a system which has closed orbit but no constant one?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you please give me an example of an ODE system which has *no constant orbit* or *fixed point* but it has *closed orbit*?

Thank you very much

Comment: What is a "constant orbit"?

Comment: it's just a fixed point

Answer (score 2):

Consider following ODE in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $\beta\ne 0$:
$$\begin{cases}
\dot{x} &= -\beta y + 2zx\\
\dot{y} &= \;\;\;\beta x + 2zy\\
\dot{z} &=   4 - x^2 - y^2 + z^2
\end{cases}
$$
We have 
$$\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2 = \beta^2 (x^2+y^2) + 16z^2 + (x^2+y^2+z^2-4)^2 \ne 0$$
over all $\mathbb{R}^3$. This flow doesn't have any fixed point at all.

On the other hand, if $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}$, then every orbit of it except the one passing through the origin is a closed orbit. To see this, embed $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $S^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4 \sim \mathbb{C}^2$ through the mapping:

$$\mathbb{R}^3 \ni (x,y,z) \quad\longrightarrow\quad (U,V) = \bigg(\frac{x+iy}{1+\frac{r^2}{4}},
\frac{z + i(1 - \frac{r^2}{4})}{1+ \frac{r^2}{4}}\bigg) \in \mathbb{C}^2$$

The ODE can be rewritten as
$$\begin{cases}\dot{U} &= \;\;\;i\beta U\\\dot{V} &= -i4V\end{cases}$$
The corresponding flow is a rotation in $U$ direction with speed $\beta$ and $V$ direction with speed $-4$. If $\beta$ is rational, then this defines a closed orbit in $S^3$ and hence one in $\mathbb{R^3}$ (except the one with $|U| = 0$ which escapes to infinity).